# Fix "Only variables should be passed by reference" PHP notice

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
if ( strcmp($file, ".") && strcmp($file, "..") 
   && !strcasecmp(end(explode(".", $file)), "mp3")) {
```

And running it results in a warning:

```
"Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
/home/caioebru/public_html/projeto/opentape/code/opentape_common.php on line 283"
```

How to get rid of it?

Comment: Need more code. "On line..." is the symptom, not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `end()` method, doc: `mixed end ( array &$array )` - as you can see it needs reference to an array and you have to have a variable to be able to do it. You must separate your code to:

```
$expFile = explode(".", $file);
if ( strcmp($file, ".") && strcmp($file, "..") && !strcasecmp(end($expFile), "mp3") { ... here your code continues
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in the second line, as I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this enigmatic code into:

```
$splFile = new SplFileInfo($file);
if($splFile->isFile() && $splFile->getExtension() == 'mp3') {
   // ...
```

You will get rid of these notices and your code will be much more readable.

See docs for [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php).

Comment: I thought it had worked, but my script stopped working. When loading the MP3, it does not list which was loaded ... Simply nothing happens when loading MP3 ... you know how I can fix this by using the script you sent me? Thank you ...

Comment: Hard to say when I cannot see the context of this piece of code. Please post full function/script source on https://gist.github.com/ or somewhere else.